# Node.js child process sudo

Tags: sudo, child-process

I am trying to use a child process that involves using sudo.

It works fine in terminal:

```
  sudo /home/pi/Desktop/fm_transmitter/bin/Release/fm_transmitter high_dash.wav 103.50
```

However, when i try it as a child process:

```
const execFile = require('child_process').execFile;
const child =execFile('sudo /home/pi/Desktop/fm_transmitter/bin/Release/fm_transmitter', ['high_dash.wav 103.50'] ,(error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    throw error;
  }
  console.log(stdout);
});
}
```

I get the following error:

/home/pi/Desktop/fm_transmitter/execFile.js:71
    throw error;
    ^

Error: spawn sudo /home/pi/Desktop/fm_transmitter/bin/Release/fm_transmitter ENOENT

How can i incorporate sudo into a child process?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Based on the execFile [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback), the `file` parameter will simply be `sudo` and everything else in the command will be the `args` parameter. So for your example it would look like this:

```
const execFile = require('child_process').execFile;
const child = execFile('sudo', ['/home/pi/Desktop/fm_transmitter/bin/Release/fm_transmitter', 'high_dash.wav', '103.50'], (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    throw error;
  }
  console.log(stdout);
});
```